# Routing Issue Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im stack with this devise routes error. The issue only in my production
server but in my local no issue.

Im using Phusion Passenger Apache. for my production setup. the error is.

```
uninitialized constant User::RegistrationsController
```

my routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'user/registrations'}
```

Path for override  controller is

```
 app/controllers/User/registrations_controller.rb
```

app/controllers/User/registrations_controller.rb

```
 class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_person!, :redirect_unless_admin


  def create
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?

  if resource.persisted?
     if resource.active_for_authentication?
     set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
    #sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    #respond_with resource, location: 
     after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  else
    set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
   # respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
end
end

private

def redirect_unless_admin
  unless current_person.is_a?(Admin)     
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end


 def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:company, :branch, :branch_id)
 end

 def account_update_params
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :branch, :company, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
end
```

Badly need help thanks.

Comment: Could you show your registrations controller please? Also the paths are always lower cased unless otherwise specified but I don't think that's causing the issue

Comment: @Mark i add the registrations_controller.rb

Comment: The path must be lowercase, `user` not `User`

Comment: Hi your correct its the upper case issue User should be user. Thanks a lot Icemen and Mark

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with your route itself, it should be users/registrations rather than user/registration.

If that still doesn't work, leave it at users/registration in the routes, and save your controller in:

```
app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
```

And change the top line to:

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

Which should fix it

EDIT: And as mentioned in initial comment, the path is all lower case